# How to query thousands of values and only return ones in array - Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase realtime database, I have data as such:

```
"users" : {
"37KfZKDwrieIEKI9juAC4Xm8aPi1" : {
  "isConnected" : false,
  "isGuestUser" : false,
  "lastOnline" : 1510250272022,
  "profilePicture" : "5a039030515e78653148",
  "userID" : "37KfZKDwrieIEKI9juAC4Xm8aPi1",
  "username" : "adsfasdfasdf"
},
"4D1GNiRH5NeRxpmTNg6JhJ3iTck1" : {
  "isConnected" : false,
  "isGuestUser" : true,
  "lastOnline" : 1510077502788,
  "profilePicture" : "5a01f2648278b6652011",
  "userID" : "4D1GNiRH5NeRxpmTNg6JhJ3iTck1",
  "username" : "ihoho"
},
"5UA3INZ7i0dnNtgX0ai5ABhjxh43" : {
  "isConnected" : false,
  "isGuestUser" : true,
  "lastOnline" : 1512610102474,
  "profilePicture" : "5a14df775a34f2388873",
  "userID" : "5UA3INZ7i0dnNtgX0ai5ABhjxh43",
  "username" : "jlkjlkjlkj"
},...
```

I am using an external API that returns a Json that looks like this

```
"candidates" : [
    {
      "enrollment_timestamp" : "1510182689539",
      "subject_id" : "37KfZKDwrieIEKI9juAC4Xm8aPi1",
    },
    {
      "enrollment_timestamp" : "1513557650425",
      "subject_id" : "CKUVZ7XtY9VKJakn1lBV7MVW1702",
    },
    {
      "enrollment_timestamp" : "1507578748901",
      "subject_id" : "l7VDdtGFpMe8BRbrlCyAciTvONk1",
    },...
```

The ultimate goal is to get all the users from the json from the external api that are online. This requires listening to the 'isConnected' endpoint in each user, and determining if it is true or false.

Now this is impossible using firebase and my current data structure, because firstly firebase does not support multiple query parameters, so I cannot do where userID = subjectID && where isConnected == true, and secondly, more importantly, firebase does not let me do the equivalent of WHERE IN, i.e. mapping userID's to an array of potential userIDs supplied client side (fyi subjectID === userID)

So what I did was restructure my data like so;

```
"onlineUsers" : {
"Aze1x7jTZIbPyyPmlUYWVdEyAd73" : true,
"CQdmMxkmqBerRGOQpFblx7SO4D33" : true,
"EptMK62Kt1Sp1EIb5meuKHVpUqs1" : true,
"J2X65KauDlSvkN4Yp5V4IF0sTnx1" : true,
"KnYEqsekY9YXV3ayOx082xw8VQX2" : true,
"aGLrKH31YvRKrB8KYQmZ4sA122m1" : true,
"ab3JZyw9YMdpW3mXkZc2BjYkxej2" : true,
"gpQic1EzSnXL9x5DhaoXxcWrGF22" : true,
"qQaBPMaDOrXrWddsijfMJWusuGG3" : true,
"tDWEUoKS4mUdQ1bWeiLTlhwCSoD3" : true
```

},

Now all I have to do to get all online users that are in the external api json is query onlineUsers with the condition parameter checking by the key. That way I know if the result is null, the user is not online:

```
    static func queryDatabase(child: String, queryEqual: String, keyOf: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (_ return: AnyObject?, _ error: String?) -> Void){
    print("querying db with child ", child)

    let ref = databaseReference.child(child).queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: queryEqual)

     ref.observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        print("subjectID: ", queryEqual, "at key ", keyOf)
        print("queryResult", snapshot)

        if let value =  (snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject])?[queryEqual] {
            print("unwrapped snapshot dict value from key: ", value)

            completionHandler(value,  nil)

        }else{
            print("no value for key \(queryEqual) so setting return as nil")

            completionHandler(nil,  nil)

        }



    }){ (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)

        completionHandler(nil,  error.localizedDescription )


    }

}
```

This function would be called simple by looping through the external api json, and calling this function ^^ every iteration, something like:

```
      for (key, valueSubjectID) in arrayOfOrderedMatches.enumerated(){
         //call function queryDatabase here

    queryDatabase(child: "onlineUsers", queryEqual: valueSubjectID, keyOf: key, completionHandler:{ (response, error) in


//it would return the user if they were online here


)}
    }
```

Now. This works. It is the most efficient way I can possible think of doing it after looking around the internet and considering every possibility. However, now onto the big problem: the json from the api can be thousands and thousands of users long. This means thousands of listeners would be being attached to check each individual user to see if they are online. This, as I have been told by a Firebase developer, is not ideal. I should not be attaching thousands of listeners. Additionally, for some reason, listeners stop being added at around 3500, i'm guessing because it bugs out. I can't remove the listeners if the query returns null (ie offline) because of the way the cache offline persistence works, and even if I could I don't think this would solve the problem. Is there any way this problem can be solved?

Comment: That's a lot of information but it's unclear why you are attaching thousands of listeners. It appears you have a node of connected users; can you just observeSingleEvent on that node by .value, put the keys in an array and iterate over each child and pull in whatever data you need from the external source? No listeners would be necessary. Maybe you could shorten (see [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and clarify the question?

Comment: observeSingleEvent is horrible and should never be used. It only listens to cache, then detaches itself so it never gets the latest server value, which is CRUCIAL in detecting whether users are online. All the information in this question is necessary in understanding the problem. Also, as I explained, the external source returns a one time json, meaning I cannot just query what data I want. The json will contain thousands of results no matter what, due to the nature of their api. Also the json tells me which users I need to query, not the other way round.

Comment: wow. lol. That's really wrong information and I am not sure where you got it from. ObserveSingleEvent is specifically for reading a value once and not leaving an observer. See the Firebase documentation [read data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).  *It only listens to cache* is incorrect as well and it absolutely gets the current value from the server (again, read the documentation). Are you stating that your app receives a JSON node *candidates* and you want to know if those specific users are online and their status is stored in Firebase?

Comment: I have read the docs very thoroughly, and spent many days trying to figure out how observations and listeners work. The docs do not explain this, but it is a consistent result that you can test: If the value has been read from the server before, it will store in cache so next time you observeSingleEvent it will get from cache. If there is no value in cache, observeSingleEvent will yes get data from server. But this cannot be used for checking if users are online, we need to always get the server value.

Comment: If you attach a listener, you can see if you print out the data returned, it always will return 2 results straight away, one from cache, then one from the server. That is proof that a single observation will result in only a cache read if there is cache available.

Comment: It can certainly be used for reading live data and we have been doing it for years (and been using Firebase for years as well). Using observeSingleEvent does not leave a listener attached and if you use that call, it will only return a single snapshot (not two). From the documentation "...a callback to be called once and then immediately removed". It will get data from the server when the call executes and it's always live data with the exception of if [Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) is enabled and you are d/c'd from the internet.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it can be used for reading live data, but only if there is no cache. You cannot forcefully make it read live data UNLESS you turn off persistence. And, I mean, who doesn't want to use persistence. If there was a way to turn off persistence for individual calls, that might solve the problem. But I don't think there is. It is persistence causing the problem (thats what I mean by cache), but it stores to cache regardless of whether you are d/c' from the interenet. And that is the problem. Also, to answer ur question from before, yes that's exactly what I want with the json

Comment: One more try: From the Firebase Docs:  "If the requested data hasn't loaded, the Firebase Realtime Database loads data from the local cache. *When network connectivity is available again*, the data loads (from the server) and will reflect the query." i.e. if the app is offline, the data is read from cache. If the app is online, the data is from the server. You can turn off persistence synching completely, or turn it on/off for specific nodes - it's totally under your control. For our use case we have it off so no data can change if a user d/c's.

Comment: Ok, I have done some testing. Turns out ref.keepSynced() is false by default, even if using persistence. This is what was causing a requirement of a double observeSingleEvent just to get the  live value. I turned it on and it seems to have stopped that problem. The docs did not explain this. They make it seem like thats the default behaviour. Now the question is, would it still be fine to observeSingleEvents of thousands of individual values? I'm pretty sure it would.

Comment: The fact that you found an API combination that works doesn't mean it's a good idea. As I said in [my comment to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029913/how-many-firebase-database-query-listeners-should-i-have-open-at-once?noredirect=1#comment83058733_48029913): you should only listen for data that the user is going to see. It doesn't matter whether you use disk persistence, keep the data synced, and/or use single-value event listeners: any data you load that the user isn't looking at is a waste of resources.

Answer (score 2):

Let me restate the objective.

> The app is provided a large list of user id's (as JSON) and the goal is to know which of those users are online.

Here's two options:

We start with a users node

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Frank"
    online: true
  uid_1
    name: "Jeff"
    online: false
```

When the JSON of the users we want to check is received, we convert it to an Array for easy access.

Then, we have a couple of options

1) Iterate over the array and observeSingleEvent for each uid to get it's current status. This won't be a query since we can directly access the uid so it will be fairly lightweight by comparison to a query.*

```
let arrayToTest = [String]() //the array of uid's to test
for uid in arrayToTest {
    let thisUserRef = self.ref.child("users").child(uid)
    thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        let status = dict["online"] as! Bool
        print("uid: \(uid) online status is: \(status)")
    })
}
```

2) Let Firebase do the heavy lifting by adding a .childAdded event to the users node, which will iterate over all of the users one at a time.

Compare the uid in the snapshot to the uid's in the array and if it matches, get it's status (on/offline) and if it doesn't exist in the array, ignore it.

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
let arrayToTest = [String]() //the array of uid's to test
usersRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let uid = dict["user_id"] as! String
    if arrayToTest.contains(uid) {
        let status = dict["online"] as! Bool
        print("uid: \(uid) online status is: \(status)")
    }
})
```

Option 2) will generally be better as it's only loading one at a time and Firebase is doing all of the work - we're just checking to see if the uid from the snapshot exists in code.

3)

As a third option we can leverage a query. Note that in the first two options we retrieved our data using the lightweight observe function. Queries are heavier by comparison and utilize more resources - however, the snapshot results are limited to only those users that are logged in, and if there are a significant amount of users may be the best option.

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
let queryRef = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "online").queryEqual(toValue: true)
let arrayToTest = [String]() //the array of uid's to test
queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let uid = dict["user_id"] as! String
    if arrayToTest.contains(uid) {
        print("uid: \(uid) online status is: true")
    }
})
```

*Firebaser's will frown on 1) as they strongly recommend against doing observes in a tight loop. So 2) if you want to get confirm every user exists and 3) if you're just interested in online users.

Comment: The reason I was using queryEquals was to avoid having to return all the users that are offline. It would use up a lot of data and take a lot of time to return all the users that are offline. I think the objective needs to be worded a tad differently, maybe add "only return users that are online", because currently it returns every user to the client regardless of whether they are online. This can't be done using option 2) unless we use our restructured data, no?

Comment: @aoeuaoeu That's a super good comment! I presented 2) as an option because I was thinking you may be interested in if users actually exist and/or take a different action if they were not online - for those cases the observe event was used. I updated the answer to include 3) which addresses your comment with a query to limit the results to just those users who are online. Note that with 10,000 users, 2) iterates through all of them in .38s through our testing. Your results may vary depending on internet speed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  For option 3 if I get all the users that are online, I could hundreds of thousands of users (also using same mechanism for active users) which becomes very slow (just tested it). What would work for option 2||3 is if instead of querying "online" I could query "userID", but for that i'd need that pesky loop as there is no WHERE IN equivalent.  Anyway, I think I can conclude that at very large numbers of users, the problem of internet speed is more of a problem than looping with observesingleevents like option 1, so sadly I think option 1 is the best bet :/

Comment: In fact, having the queryequal seems to cause firebase to be slow when there are lots of users. Hmm. I take back what I said. There are problems with both, but I'll have to use option2

Comment: @aoeuaoeu To reiterate, even with tens of thousands of users in the users node, option 3) will only return return the ones where online is true, and if that is a few thousand users, it will be very very fast. That being said, there may be better options of how to handle situations where you would actually need to process thousands of users at one time.